# Need help with explanation of my solution.

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to solve a problem... Got all the theory in hands. Not sure where to begin though... I have just started learning hypothesis testing and this is one of the problems I found on-line. Can't find any examples on how to approach this problem.

Here it is:

The following data were generated from an uniform random variable on
$ [0; \theta] $

0.21497701  0.14558536  0.14723886  0.14085940 0.25509078  0.29657258

0.36503504  0.39098790  0.05300265  0.43664128 0.19570767  0.26962860

0.45779867  0.23034297  0.18053900  0.23119600 0.27987027  0.07165117

0.14081384  0.05295966

We want to test $ H_0 : \theta = 1/2 $ against $  \theta > 1/2 $ using the likelihood ratio test.

Find the critical value for size $ \alpha $ test.

Here is my attempt to solve it:
[image]

One thing I can't explain well: why I'm choosing the $max(X_1,...,X_n)$ as my test statistics? Intuitively, I know this should be the best choice but can't figure out good explanation...

I would appreciate any constructive advice!

Comment: You'll want to compare your observed sample mean to your hypothetical mean

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis testing for the uniform distribution does not flow conveniently from the likelihood ratio because all uniform density functions are flat.

To begin, let's take a simple vs. simple example and use only one observation.
Suppose we're testing $H_0: \theta = 1/2$ against $H_1: \theta = 1$.
If the sample value lies above 1/2, you know for **sure** that $H_0$ 
needs to be rejected (significance level 0). So the rejection region
needs to contain all of $(1/2, 1)$. If you want a test at level $\alpha = .05$, then technically
you can include into the rejection region any subinterval of $(1, 1/2)$
of length .025 (area .05 under the curve) that you like.

Think about the LR test for one and two observations and try to figure
out how it might be used. Boundaries are important.

For your specific data, you have no observation above 1/2. If you did
the decision would not be in any doubt. You have one value "pretty close"
to 1/2. Does it tempt you to reject the null hypothesis?

Uniform distributions are the source of lots of pathological examples in
hypothesis testing and inference. [One *inference* problem that works out
nicely is to find the sufficient statistic for estimating $\theta$ in $Unif(0, \theta)$, check if it is complete, and then to find an unbiasing factor to get the UMVUE. I believe there is a discussion of that example on this site.